# Как привязать кручение колесика мыши в Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, mousewheel

Как мне привязать кручение колесика мыши в *Tkinter*?

Я использую *Windows*.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter as tk


def mouse_wheel(event):
    global count
    if event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
        count -= 1
    if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
        count += 1
    label['text'] = count
    
count = 0
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Поверните колесо мыши')
root['bg'] = 'darkgreen'

# Windows 
root.bind("<MouseWheel>", mouse_wheel)

# Linux 
#root.bind("<Button-4>", mouse_wheel)
#root.bind("<Button-5>", mouse_wheel)

label = tk.Label(root, font=('courier', 18, 'bold'), width=10)
label.pack(padx=40, pady=40)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]