# Действие при прокрутке колеса мыши вверх

Tags: python, tkinter, binding

У меня есть маленький вопрос касательно функции bind'а в модуле Tkinter.
Я хочу что бы при прокрутке колеса мыши вверх(вперед) выполнялось действие, но я не знаю какой должен быть аргумент для указания движения колеса вперед. `<MouseWheel>` не подходит, производится реакция на все движения.
Помогите мне.
Не работающий код с bind:

```
window.bind("<Control-MouseWheel>", func)
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Innokentie  Вот [этот вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355902/tkinter-binding-mousewheel-to-scrollbar#41505949) вам не подойдёт?

Comment: Издеваетесь? Так json, tkinter, discord или вообще чего? А код где?

Comment: Victor VosMottor Я имею в виду модуль Tkinter, не о каком json и discord речь не идет. А вариант GrAnd к сожалению не подходит, тут в другом дело

Comment: @Innokentie до моей правки заголовок вопроса был "Проблемма с Json в Discord.py"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так работает:

```
def mouse_wheel(event):
    if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
        # Do something


# Windows
root.bind("<MouseWheel>", mouse_wheel)

# Linux
# root.bind("<Button-4>", mouse_wheel)
# root.bind("<Button-5>", mouse_wheel)
```

Взял из: [Как привязать кручение колесика мыши в Tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1199781/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%B2-tkinter)